# I used Angular CLI: 9.1.2, Node: 12.16.2 and OS: linux x64 version. I get the following errors

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, typescript

I used Angular CLI: 9.1.2, Node: 12.16.2 and OS: linux x64 version. I also used the login page and webphone page for Angular.

webphone.component.html looks like this:

```
<div class="row cnt">
<audio autoplay width='0' hieght='0' id="audio"></audio>
<div class="col-lg-3">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="panel panel-primary" id="controls">
<div class='form-group row' id="registration_control" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;" >
<div class='col-lg-9'>
<input type="text" class='form-control b-r-sm' ngStyle="{'background-image': 'url(' + regStatusBackgroundImage + ')'}" [value]="reg_status" id="reg_status" readonly>
</div>
</div>
<div class='form-group row' id="dial_control" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;" >
<div class='col-lg-9'>
<input type="text" style="font-size: x-large;height: 40px;" name="digits" class='form-control form-control-lg p-sm b-r-sm' ngModel="digitsValue" id="digits"/>
</div>
<div class='col-lg-3'>
<button class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-block" id="dial" on-click="dialButton();"><i id="dial_icon" class="fa fa-phone" ngClass="{'text-danger' : dialIconTextDanger}"></i> </button>
</div>
</div>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { WebphoneComponent } from './webphone/webphone.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login'},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'webphone', component: WebphoneComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When I type `ng serve` on the command line:

```
 ng serve
```

I get these errors:

> ERROR in src/app/webphone/webphone.component.html:11:53 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
>
> 11 
>   src/app/webphone/webphone.component.ts:7:16
>   7 templateUrl: './webphone.component.html',
>                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Error occurs in the template of component WebphoneComponent.
>   src/app/webphone/webphone.component.html:21:129 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
>
> 21 src/app/webphone/webphone.component.ts:7:16
>   7   templateUrl: './webphone.component.html',
>
> Error occurs in the template of component WebphoneComponent.
>   src/app/webphone/webphone.component.html:24:133 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'i'.
>
> 24
>
> src/app/webphone/webphone.component.ts:7:16

I have used the following link from StackOverflow but not working for me.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cant-bind-to-ngstyle-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-ion-navbar-solved/73643

Please let me know if any answer for anyone.
Thank you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ngClass and ngStyle should be wrapped inside [] as they are inputs to the ngClass/ngStyle directives. This is used when your directive and the input has the same name.

Also when using ngModel you need to import formsModule

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

[...]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    [...]
    FormsModule
  ],
  [...]
})
```